Testing "fprint" on Winston
I'm trying to unit test Winston logger. My issue is to test format of logger. I managed to write a successfull test for this but it does not cover AxiosError case and the arguments I called with spy are not plain and does not seem to me right. The code is;
import winston from 'winston'

winston.addColors({
    error: 'red',
    warn: 'yellow',
    info: 'green',
    http: 'magenta',
    verbose: 'white',
    debug: 'white',
    silly: 'gray',
})

const myFormat = winston.format.printf((log) => {
    if (log.details) {
        const message = log.details.reduce(
            (accumulator: any, currentValue: any) =>
                accumulator + currentValue.message + '\n',
            ''
        )

        return `${log.timestamp} ${log.level}: ${message}`
    }

    if (log.name == 'AxiosError' && log.response) {
        const message = `${log.response.status} ${log.response.config.url} ${log.response.data}`
        return `${log.timestamp} ${log.level}: ${message}`
    }

    return `${log.timestamp} ${log.level}: ${log.message}`
})

const format = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:ms' }),
    winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
    winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
    myFormat
)

const transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console({
        format: format,
    }),
]

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    exitOnError: false,
    level: 'debug',
    levels: {
        error: 0,
        warn: 1,
        info: 2,
        http: 4,
        verbose: 4,
        debug: 5,
        silly: 6,
    },
    transports: transports,
})

export default logger

Test code I tried is;
import { createSandbox, assert } from 'sinon'
import logger from './logger'
import winston from 'winston/lib/winston/config'

const sandbox = createSandbox()

describe('All Validator Logger Tests', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {})

    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore()
    })

    describe('Logger', () => {
        it('should work perfectly', async () => {
            sandbox.stub(winston, 'addColors').returns()
            sandbox.useFakeTimers(new Date('2024-05-30 13:03:24:324'))
            const loggingTransportSpy = sandbox.spy(logger.transports[0], 'log')

            const simpleExample = 'exampleMessage'
            logger.info(simpleExample)

            expect(loggingTransportSpy.called).toBe(true)

            assert.calledWith(
                loggingTransportSpy,
                sandbox.match({
                    message: '\x1B[32mexampleMessage\x1B[39m',
                    level: '\x1B[32minfo\x1B[39m',
                    timestamp: '2024-05-30 13:03:24:324',
                })
            )
        })

        it('should log AxiosError', async () => {
            sandbox.useFakeTimers(new Date('2024-05-30 12:34:56:789'))
            const loggingTransportSpy = sandbox.spy(logger.transports[0], 'log')

            const axiosErrorExample = {
                name: 'AxiosError',
                response: {
                    status: 404,
                    config: { url: '/test-url' },
                    data: 'Not Found',
                },
            }
            logger.error(axiosErrorExample)

            expect(loggingTransportSpy.called).toBe(true)

            assert.calledWith(loggingTransportSpy, {
                message:
                    '\x1B[31m{\x1B[39m\n' +
                    "\x1B[31m  name: 'AxiosError',\x1B[39m\n" +
                    "\x1B[31m  response: { status: 404, config: { url: '/test-url' }, data: 'Not Found' }\x1B[39m\n" +
                    '\x1B[31m}\x1B[39m',
                level: '\x1B[31merror\x1B[39m',
                timestamp: '2024-05-30 12:34:56:3456',
            })
        })

        it('should format a detailed message correctly', () => {
            sandbox.useFakeTimers(new Date('2024-05-30 12:34:56:789'))
            const loggingTransportSpy = sandbox.spy(logger.transports[0], 'log')

            const detailedMessageExample = {
                details: [{ message: 'Detail 1' }, { message: 'Detail 2' }],
            }
            logger.info(detailedMessageExample)

            assert.calledWith(
                loggingTransportSpy,
                sandbox.match({
                    message:
                        "\x1B[32m{ details: [ { message: 'Detail 1' }, { message: 'Detail 2' } ] }\x1B[39m",
                    level: '\x1B[32minfo\x1B[39m',
                    timestamp: '2024-05-30 12:34:56:3456',
                })
            )
        })
    })
})


Instead of {message: '\x1B[32mexampleMessage\x1B[39m', level: '\x1B[32minfo\x1B[39m', timestamp: '2024-05-30 13:03:24:324'} I feel like I need to use something I see on my console like 2024-05-30 13:03:24:324 info: exampleMessage. But it does not work that way.
